# Why is my auto fill not working?

Tags: vba, excel

Hoping you can help with the below, I've no idea why this isn't working and I can't seem to figure it out. After some Googling, I can't even find another example of this issue.

Essentially the code should take data on one page, place HLOOKUPS in another page to sort everything into the right columns (all working fine). Then once that's done, it should auto fill down using the row count.

The problem I have, is that it is auto filling on the wrong sheet (it might be worth calling out that the sheet it fills is the same one the code is in and where the rowcnt is.

I tried to explicitly call out the sheet I want to use as such: `Range("A2:V2").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(5).Range("A3:V" & rowcnt), Type:=xlFillDefault` but this then throws an Application-defined or object-defined error on the fill line of code.

```
Public Sub FormatData()

    rowcnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet4.Range("B:B")) + 1

With Sheets("Final Datasets")
    .Cells(2, "A").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=HLOOKUP(""oOrder_date"",'Teradata Downloads'!R1:R1048576,ROW('Final Datasets'!RC),0)"

[snip] load more of the same as above [/snip]

        'FILL
        Range("A2:V2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:V" & rowcnt), Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

End Sub
```

I'm properly puzzled here, so any help you can give as to how to fix this (and more importantly, why it's happening) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have the AutoFill in the With Statement, try to use the "." before the Range.

Also, the destination must include the source range.

```
.Range("A2:V2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:V" & rowcnt)
```

Comment: I was very hopefuly but unfortunately didn't work. I tried to take it out the with statement and add the sheet: `Sheets(5).Range("A2:V2").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(5).Range("A3:V" & rowcnt), Type:=xlFillDefault`, but also unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Ignore my last comment - edited some other things and worked - thank you!

Comment: @StevenWalker. Glad to hear. What was the Problem?

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not entirely sure - I tweaked a few things and one of them seemed to work! One of them was I changed A3 to A2 so maybe this?

Comment: Yes, per the [`Range.AutoFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) docs, the destination must include the source range, so definitely `A2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is changing the A3 to A2 that fixed it. An Autofill destination has to include the line you are Autofilling from. The 'destination' has to include the 'source', in other words.